# Can't de-serialized my JSON response using the System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer class

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

**I'm using `System.Text.Json` to de-serialize my `JSON`, I know about `Json.Net` and choose not to use it.**

I'm making a request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ using the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsync` method which returns a string. The response to the request is a `JSON` array populated with objects with the following keys:`userId`, `id`, `title` and `body`. I'm de-serializing my `JSON` using the `Deserialize` `generic` method, where `Posts` is my return type and `response` is my string.

By catching Exceptions I get the error shown bellow.

**I currently have**

```cs
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await GetPostAsync();

        }

        static async Task GetPostAsync()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");

            string location = "posts";

            try
            {
                string response = await client.GetStringAsync(location);

                Posts deserializedPosts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Posts>(response);

                Console.WriteLine(deserializedPosts);

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        class Posts
        {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string body { get; set; }
        }
```

**The error I received**

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to fugo.Program+Posts. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleStartArray(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at fugo.Program.GetPostAsync() in /home/kepler/PROJECTS/C-SHARP/fugo/Program.cs:line 27
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post an example of your payload. Many times, problems like these are caused by double serialization or invalid characters or some combination thereof. Can you post what is being posted over the wire?

Comment: by payload do you mean the response?

Comment: @RossBush -- it's in the code: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Posts deserializedPosts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Posts>(response);
```

to this:

```
var deserializedPosts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Posts>>(response);
```

The data returned is an array, not an object.